# Cookie with multiple expiration dates

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie, with a 60 day expiration time. The cookie sets which TOWN the user has selected for our site. We also want to have a popup window open upon page loading ... but want that to happen every week (and have the cookie check if "it's been over two weeks").

We are trying to avoid setting TWO cookies. I assume I can do this by checking how long 'til the cookie expires, then figure out when the start date was (based on the $number_of_days), and then calculate 2 weeks from the start date, and THEN see if the date/time has passed. However, my php knowledge is pretty limited. Wondering if anyone has done this before and can show me how...  I just need a variable outputted states whether 2 weeks has passed or not (i.e. $openpopup=1);

I am using the following code for my cookie (single expiration date)...

```
$number_of_days = 60 ;
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * $number_of_days ;
if(isset($town)) { 
    // Set Cookies
    setcookie( "towns", $town, $date_of_expiry, "/" ); 
} else {
    // Del Cookies
    unset($_COOKIE['towns']);
    // empty value and expiration one hour before
    setcookie('towns', '', time() - 3600);
}
```

Comment: Tricky thing here is that you cannot read the expiry time/date of a cookie directly. Easiest way around that is unfortunately to set two cookies, the first would be the cookie you are setting now, and the second would be just to hold the expiry date of the first cookie. You could then use the value of that second cookie to calculate the times. With just the one cookie however you wouldn't be able to do what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read the expiration date back once the cookie has been set.  You can only get the key=value pairs.  If you need the date then you need to set it as part of the data in the cookie itself.

You could set multiple pieces of data in an array and the serialize it and store it in the cookie.  Then you would unserialize it when you read it back.

Comment: You are starting to lose me... how do I set actual piece data (the code for the cookie, I grabbed from somewhere - it wasn't written by myself)

Comment: Yes, that would work.  You'll have to serialize it before you set it then unserialize it when you read it.  I'm going to edit my answer to include that.